# Button background color darkens in safari when video autoplaying in Svelte

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

So I noticed when I added playsinline into the video attributes to enable autoplay, the button below gets darkened and dimmed. This only happens when it's running on safari in on my iphone. I've tried adding a z-index to the button and also a background color in the to the video in styles. Any suggestions.

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline preload="auto" class="videos">
                <source src={vid} type="video/webm" />
                <track kind="captions" /></video
            >
```

Thanks

Comment: is the`>` of closing `</video` tag is just misplaced here only or in the project also?

Comment: it is the closing, prettier made it skip to the next line for some reason